# carla leaderboard error:Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in WorldSettings.__init__(WorldSettings) did not match C++ signature

Tags: python, carla

I'm learning the tutorial on https://leaderboard.carla.org/get_started/#11-download-the-carla-leaderboard-package%22, but when I run ./test_run.sh, the error occurred.

```
Trt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mi/PycharmProjects/CarlaLeaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard_evaluator.py", line 478, in <module>
main()
File "/home/mi/PycharmProjects/CarlaLeaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard_evaluator.py", line 467, in main
leaderboard_evaluator = LeaderboardEvaluator(arguments, statistics_manager)
File "/home/mi/PycharmProjects/CarlaLeaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard_evaluator.py", line 79, in __init__
  self.client, self.client_timeout, self.traffic_manager = self._setup_simulation(args)
File "/home/mi/PycharmProjects/CarlaLeaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard/leaderboard_evaluator.py", line 178, in _setup_simulation
spectator_as_ego = False
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
WorldSettings.__init__(WorldSettings)
did not match C++ signature:
__init__(_object*, bool synchronous_mode=False, bool no_rendering_mode=False, double fixed_delta_seconds=0.0, bool substepping=True, double max_substep_delta_time=0.01, int max_substeps=10, float max_culling_distance=0.0, bool deterministic_ragdolls=False, float tile_stream_distance=3000.0, float actor_active_distance=2000.0)
__init__(_object*)
```

My system version is Ubuntu 20.04, and the python version is 3.7.All the packages are downloaded by steps, I want to know how I can fix the error, and the the sample code.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too when I was using variables to populate the WeatherParameters, e.g.:

```
cloudiness = 100
precipitation = 100
weather = WeatherParameters(
    cloudiness = cloudiness,  # range from 0 to 100
    precipitation = precipitation,  # range from 0 to 100
    sun_altitude_angle= 90 # degrees, 90 is midday, -90 is midnight
)
```

When I hard-coded the values, the error went away for me:

```
    weather = WeatherParameters(
    cloudiness = 100,  
    precipitation = 100, 
    sun_altitude_angle= 90 
)
```